# Background color and image on li hover at same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code where I want to apply a image and also background color at the same time. Can anyone help me with it?

CSS

```
    .menu, .menu ul
{
    width:1000px;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    margin: 0;

}
.menu{  padding: 0; height:30px;}
.menu li
{
    float: left;
    padding-top:3px;
    height:20px;
    text-align:left;
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:10px 15px 0 15px;
    background:url(../image/border.png) no-repeat right center;
}

.menu li:hover
{       
    background:#3EBBEC; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.menu a { text-decoration: none; color:#000000; }
.menu a:hover { text-transform:lowercase; }
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
   <a href="#"><li>A</li></a>  
   <a href="#"><li>B</li></a> 
   <a href="#"><li>C</li></a>
   <a href="#"><li>D</li></a>   
</ul>
```

This is the code of both HTML and CSS where I need to apply an image and also a bckground color at the same time. Please someone help me with this.

Comment: first... your HTML tag is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
.menu li:hover 
{ 
background:#3EBBEC url(image.jpg) no-repeat;
color: #FFFFFF; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the short-hand notation when you only want to change single values. Or the other way , if you use the short-hand notation, supply all values you don't want to be "default" values.

Use:

```
.menu li:hover
{       
    background-color: #3EBBEC; 
}
```

or:

```
.menu li:hover
{       
    background: #3EBBEC url(...) ...; 
}
```

Just remember that when you use the short-hand, that all values not provided will fallback to it's default not to it's inherited values.

Comment: then how can I apply an image also on that

Comment: @Jhilom use the appropriate properties, e.g. `background-image`, `background-position` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
.menu li {
    background: #color url(path to img);
}
.menu li:hover {
    background: #hover-color url(path to hover-img);
    /* or if only color is changed just write */
    background-color: #hover-color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First your HTML should look like this

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.menu li{display:block; width:100px; height:30px; background:url(yourbackgroundimage.png);}
ul.menu li a{display:block; width:100px; height:30px; background:url(yoursecondbackgroundimage.png);}
```

and if you like to add hover state

```
ul.menu li{display:block; width:100px; height:30px; background:url(yourbackgroundimage.png);}
ul.menu li:hover{background:url(yourhoverbackgroundimage.png);}
ul.menu li a, ul.menu li a:visited{display:block; width:100px; height:30px; background:url(yoursecondbackgroundimage.png);}
ul.menu li a:hover{background:url(yoursecondbackgroundimagehover.png);}
```